# Can't insert file's path into database.(I'm New to HTML and PHP)

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload the file's path into my database. But nothing is being inserted. My file gets uploaded to target directory successfully. I want to insert the path too, but can't do it. I believe I'm doing some mistake in the Insert Into statement. Please let me know what's wrong? 
My upload.php code is below:

```
<?php
  // variables
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','abcdef','trademark');

    if(!$conn)  { 
    echo "Not Connected To Server";
    } 
else {


  define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/'); 
  $fileName = $_FILES['file'];



    // check for which action should be taken if file already exist

    //Rename file name
    if(file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $fileName['name'])) 
    {
    $updatedFileName = update_file_name(UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($fileName['tmp_name'], $updatedFileName);

    echo"FILE SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADED!! " . "<br/><br/><br/>"; //after renaming
    }




    // If no such file already exists, then upload it as it is
    else
    {
    move_uploaded_file($fileName['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']);

    echo " FILE SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADED!! ". "<br/><br/>";
    }


    // function to rename file
    function update_file_name($file) 
    {
    $pos = strrpos($file,'.');
    $ext = substr($file,$pos); 
    $dir = strrpos($file,'/');
    $dr  = substr($file,0,($dir+1)); 

    $arr = explode('/',$file);
    $fName = trim($arr[(count($arr) - 1)],$ext);

    $exist = FALSE;
    $i = 2;

    while(!$exist)
    {
    $file = $dr.$fName.'_'.$i.$ext;

    if(!file_exists($file))
        $exist = TRUE;

     $i++;
    }

    return $file;
    } // function to rename ends

    $sql = "INSERT INTO file (Path) VALUES (' " . mysqli_real_escape_string( UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']) . " ')";
    $r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  echo 'file info inserted';
}


?>
```

[image: This happens after I submit the form:]

[image: This is my db record after the form is submitted]

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's pretty hard to follow the flow when it looks like this. Also, what actually happens? Errors? Wrong/empty value in DB? No row inserted at all? Checked your servers error log?

Comment: You should look into [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Even `mysqli_real_escape_string()` has some security issues in certain situations.

Comment: Since you are new comer, you should try to do more debugging for problems like that. i.e you have first sure that `mysqli_real_escape_string( UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name'])`  is not empty.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i've updated the question, and empty value is inserted in db

Comment: Have you checked your error log? A good idea is also to turn `display_errors` on in your local PHP environment. Read more here: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) As the answer below states, you're using [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) wrong and you should get an error about that.

Answer (score 0):

Check syntax for function `mysqli_real_escape_string`

getting warning message as,

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1
>   given in